# How to suppress warnings of grammar generated in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

Warnings like below :

> rule contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string. Example : row_limiting_clause in Oracle where both offset_clause and fetch_clause are optional

```
row_limiting_clause : offset_clause? fetch_clause? ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot suppress such warnings and you should take them serious. Even though ANTLR4 can generate a valid ATN from this grammar, it might make unexpected decisions, depending on the input.

Instead try to fix the grammar part. The warning is about something like:

```
a: b?;
b: c? d?;
c: 'C';
d:'D';
```

What you see here is that rule `b` is not only optional as a whole, but also all its parts are. Which is kinda duplicating the optionality. You could write instead `a: b;` without changing the language that is parsed with this grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes to your grammar:

```
row_limiting_clause : offset_clause? | offset_clause fetch_clause? ;
```

and if `row_limitic_clause` is truly optional, use `row_limitic_clause?` wherever you use it.

That will mean that row_limiting_clause will only match if an `offset_clause` and/or a `fetch_clause` is present.

Comment: There is no need to make row_limitic_clause optional since it could already match nothing.